# Inserting Gif in VB6 Program

Tags: vb6, loading, gif

I have created a new VB6 program and i would like to put a gif in so it can play on the loading screen. I have searched online on how to do it and it shows you have to use a web browser and picture box to view it. i know how to insert the web browser and picture box. I do not know how to code it with the gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways, but the simplest way is to use a picture box and web browser. The code to use is this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim loc As String
    loc = App.Path & "where the gif is located\somegif.gif"
    Animation.Navigate "about:" & "<html>" & "<body leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scroll=no>" _
    & "<img src=""" & loc & """></img></body></html>"
End Sub
```